# Android. How to correctly hide status bar programatically on device with display cutout

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a viewPager in my app with 2 fragments. And when you swipe to one of them I want to hide the status bar. Here's this code:

```
val hideFlag: Int =
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY

activity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = hideFlag
```

Everything worked pretty well on normal devices, but there are several problems on devices with display cutout.

1) When status bar shows or hides the whole UI does some re-layout and jumps

2) If the status bar is hidden and you make a swipe from the top of the screen your app will just crash with no logs and no dialog about the error.

Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the problem #2. Here's code from Activity.onTochEvent:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (mWindow.shouldCloseOnTouch(this, event)) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

So window decides to finish a current activity. I don't know why this code even exists, but I have overridden this method in my base activity, so it always returns false and everything seems to be fine.

Still have problems with problem #1 though.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I'm having the same problem. Thank you

Comment: There is no reason to hide the status bar on a device with cutout, cause this space will be just unsued. Don't hide the status bar or use all available space with LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES flag